# How can I convert a hour range to a total number of hours using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark, databricks

I'm currently working with Yelp's dataset and my objective is to find the total hours a business is open a week. From the data, I am able to extract a time range for each day that looks like "9:0-0:0" or "17:30-21:30" for a certain day. How can I use SQL to get a single value for these hourly ranges?

This is some code I used to simply show the hours for a business in the dataset.

```
df_busSelected = df_business.select("business_id", "name"
                   , "hours.Sunday", "hours.Monday", "hours.Tuesday"
                   ,"hours.Wednesday", "hours.Thursday", "hours.Friday"
                   , "hours.Saturday")
df_busSelected.show()
```

I hope to make a new column with the total hours a business is open a week with the given ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Using pyspark, you can do something like the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('h', expr('split(hours, "[-:]")').astype('array<int>')) \
  .withColumn('h1', expr('''
        h[2] - h[0] + IF(h[2]<h[0],24,0) + round((h[3]-h[1])/60,0)
   ''').astype('int')) \
  .show()
+----------+-----------+----------------+---+
|     bdate|      hours|               h| h1|
+----------+-----------+----------------+---+
|2019-10-17|    9:0-0:0|    [9, 0, 0, 0]| 15|
|2019-10-18|17:30-21:30|[17, 30, 21, 30]|  4|
+----------+-----------+----------------+---+
```

First use the charset `[-:]` to split the column `hours` into an array of 4 items (named `h`) and cast it into array of `int` (originally array of StringType)

Then do the simple math and at the end cast the result type to `int` again.

Next, use `date_format('bdate', 'EEEE')` to get week name and then use `groupby` and `pivot` and probably `agg` + `sum` functions to get the final result

Comment: hey, I was working with the expr you gave me (very helpful, thank you) but I was wondering why when I apply the equation, some values under "h1" are rounded down, is this because of the round((h[3]-h[1])? I also get some negative values for hours and had some concerns about that, please let me know if you can help with the equation part!

Comment: @ChristineBui, you can convert the numbers to minutes and do the math which is better than my original method: `((h[2] - h[0] + IF(h[2]<h[0],24,0))*60 + h[3] - h[1])/60`. for negative `h1`, most likely there are some data issues, just check the array field `h` should help troubleshooting this issue.